# instance_variable_get not working throws nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I use instance variable here?

**RUBY**

```
 codes = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
 codes.each do |code|
   iv =  instance_variable_get("@#{code}_resource")
   puts iv.inspect
  end
```

iv gives nil error.I need an output like @a_resource or @b_resource ...

Comment: Instance variables you try to get are uninitialized, so attempt to get value returns `nil`.

Comment: Could you show the error message?

Comment: You don't have any instance variable with name @a_resource

Comment: Actually which instance variable are you trying to get? 
Please see this link: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get

Comment: @MarekLipka - Add this as ans

Comment: I suggest you remove the Rails tags, as this is a pure-Ruby question. Superfluous tags cause some to waste time and others (who filter out on certain tags) to not see a question that might interest them.

Comment: `nil` has an `inspect` method. It is 100% impossible to get an error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one instance variable you try to get is uninitialized, so attempt to get its value returns `nil`.